# React Native Async operation with ProgressDialog as one function

Tags: react-native, callback, progressdialog

I want to create a method or a class in React Native that preform a background operation while opening a progress dialog then hides the progress dialog when the background operation is done.

Logically this would be done using a call back :

```
 export const doWithProgressDialog = async (callback) => 
    {
       // show progress dialog
       await callback();
       // hide progress dialog
    }
```

However as you can see , what I'm encountering is that i have to return a progress dialog component component before the callback is called so that the progress dialog would be rendered.

Even if i make a component class that renders a progress dialog instead of a function , i will have the same issue in render method inside component class.